# Parsing the Perl script command(s) and get the ARGV

Tags: perl, parsing, command, argv

I have around 100 different scripts and command will look like below

1. perl scriptone.pl --option1 PRODUCTION 100
2. perl scripttwo.pl --option1 UAT 101
3. perl scriptthree.pl --option1 TESTING 102

I need to get the ARGV (PRODUCTION,100 for 1, UAT,101 for 2) of all the above script without executing perl script.

Is there a way to get the ARGV using SHELL script or using anyother perl options?

Comment: You want help parsing shell commands, and you don't even specify for which shell?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you need **obtain** the arguments inside perl script itself without it's execution? Or you have some **shell script** which runs this commands in sequence and you want to extract these arguments from this **shell script**?

Comment: @PolarBear yes I need to get the arguments of a given perl script without execution. i.e given a perl script get the ARGV of the script without actually executing(perl scriptone.pl --option1 PRODUCTION 100 , if i give this, it should return argv as PRODUCTION,100)

Comment: @Anonymous So you are not interested in executing `scriptone.pl`? You simply want to parse the **string**: `"perl scriptone.pl --option1 PRODUCTION 100"` to extract the text following the sub pattern `--option1` ?

Answer (score 3):

For commands similar to the specific shell commands you posted, you can start with following:

```
@ARGV = split ' ', $cmd;
splice @ARGV, 0, 2;
```

From there, you can extract the values from `@ARGV` using the same code that `scriptone.pl` does.

Comment: issue is sometimes command will be like 'perl scriptone.pl PROD 101 --option1 --option2 232'

Comment: Updated my answer. (I'm not going to guess how `scriptone.pl` extracts the desired value from `@ARGV` since it clearly accepts unusual patterns.)